# Publish binaries in a package - more info

Tags: cme, razormediator

I have some doubts related to "Publish binaries in a package" default TBB referred in Default Finish Actions.

Created the Component Template and added  default finish actions TBB in my CT.

CT Design contains below code:

```
<img src ="@Component.Id" alt="",title=""/>
```

After publishing the page image link resolved to below url:

```
<img src="/country/images/binarypoc.png" alt="" ,title="">
```

By default SDL Tridion appends the TCM URI to the filename to make it unique. But in this case image file name doesn't contains any tcm-id. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using Razor Mediator for your templates. Razor Mediator have the capability to automatically add Binaries to to the Package

```
 <razor.mediator extractBinaries="true" adminUser="INSERT TRIDION USERNAME">
```

It seems that while Razor Mediator adds the Multimedia Components to the Package it populates the `FileName` property with the Multimedia Component File Name but it doesn't add a `FileNameSuffix`

`Engine.AddBinary()` is executed by the `Publish Binaries In Package` TBB. It will internally call to the `Item.ConstructFileName()` which will concatenate `Item.Properties["FileName"]` and `Item.Properties["FileNameSuffix"]`

If `Item.Properties["FileNameSuffix"]` is not populated then you will only get the File Name

If you want the `TCMURI` as a `FileNameSuffix` the you will need to add a new TBB that look for all the Multimedia Components in the Package and populates that property

Comment: There is an existing open source TBB which does this - check out the Force Unique Binary Filenames TBB in http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/generic-2011-tbbs.aspx

Comment: yes...we are using Razor Mediator for our templates...also I agree with your answer..

Comment: I have one more question...in case of DWT Templates will it append tcm-id to the filename?

Comment: The TBB mentioned by Will in his comment above will add the tcm-id to the filename of each image outputted by the DWT TBB.